# php - wrong textual/numerical day of the week

Tags: php, date

```
$thedate = "2014-11-01 00:32";
echo $thedate; = 2014-11-01 00:32 = ok
$pd = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($thedate));
echo $pd; = 2014-11-01 = ok
$dow = date("l",$pd);/$dow = date("w",$pd);
echo $dow; = Wednesday/3 = not OK - 2014-11-01 is Saturday/6
```

I thought it misplaced the day and month but January 11 is also Saturday. What's wrong?

Comment: Where and when is $parkdate ?

Comment: You are passing string (`2014-11-01` in `$pd`) as second argument, instead of timestamp

Comment: dev-null-dweller: Thanks a lot, can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing string (**2014-11-01** in `$pd`) as second argument, instead of timestamp to the `date` function